# How to make podlinkcheck not complain about URLs with a fragment

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have a Perl module with a `L<...>` link like this:

```perl
=head1 ...

See L<RFC 8250|https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-4>.

=cut

1;
```

When I run [`podlinkcheck`](https://metacpan.org/pod/podlinkcheck) (version 15) on it, it complains:

```sh
themodule.pm:3:5: no module/program/pod "https:"
```

even though [perldoc perlpod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod#Formatting-Codes) says:

> Or you can link to a web page:
>
> Lscheme:...
>
> L<text|scheme:...>
>
> Links to an absolute URL. For example, Lhttp://www.perl.org/ or L<The Perl Home Page|http://www.perl.org/>.

I want to keep using `podlinkcheck` for all my actual Perl module links, but how do I tell it to treat links that start with `https://` as hyperlinks instead of looking for a Perl module by that name?

(It seems to work when I remove the fragment (i.e., `See L<RFC 8250|https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259>` but especially for long documents I want to link to a particular section, not just the whole thing. Escaping the `#` with a backslash and putting double quotes around it did not help.)

Comment: Glancing at the source, it doesn't do any checking to see if a link is a URL; just looks for manpages and treats everything else as a module name. File a bug report? (Looks like it'd be a few lines to make it skip urls)

Comment: Untested: Before line 202 of App/PodLinkCheck.pm, add `next if $type eq 'url';`